# Netbean RCP Dependency build

Tags: netbeans, ant

I'm using **Netbean RCP** to develop my desktop application.
my goal is to use the "cruise control" for overnight builds.
I just can't find any information of how to build all Java sources to compounded jar (consisting of all netbeans modules).
I want also to be able to define that if ,for instance,case the **org.openide** jar is missing, it will d/l it as need.
I have 2 questions:

1. can i run the IDE automatic build outside of netbeans IDE?
2. how can i define the internal\external dependencies for my project.

Answer (score 0):

1. Netbeans use an ant file for conducting the 'background' builds, if you haven't specified a build file yourself.
2. You can use [ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) if you wish to stick with ant or you can use [maven](http://maven.apache.org/), which was designed for exactly this task